# How to set counter as per status(Pass Fail)of the test case

Tags: eclipse, session, selenium-webdriver, file-handling, session-state

On every execution of the automated script, a counter should be incremented but for the today's system date. As the system date changes, the counter should resent to 0 and start numbering as 1,2,3 and so on based on as many times the script is executed. I want to write the date along with the number of attempts of the testcase in a .txt log file.

Today, if script is run for the 1st time then value printed in file should be  attempt=1 and so on. If the script is run tomorrow then date should be tomorrows date and the counter of attempt should start with 1,2 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder with the name today's date and in that folder create a text file  with starting value as 0.Next time when you run the test in same day read the value from the text file from created text file and increment by 1 and use that value and also write the same value to text file and save it.
the above one  is just a concept and you have to  write a script in such a way that every time when you run the script "it first checks the folder with today's date exits or not and if no folder present it should create a folder with today's date and also it should create a fresh text file in side it".
try to implement it you will get what you want.